# Converting string to date format 0000-00-00 before extracting year and month information

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string column (object type):

```
Date
2020-06-15
2019-07-23
Data non available
```

How can I convert the string `Data non available` and/or any missing values to the format `0000-00-00`, before extracting the month and the year?

I can convert the `Date` column to `datetime`, and extract information on year and month from the other rows, but then I get this error:

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: Data not available
```

My code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date_Year'], df['Date_month'] = df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month
```

Expected output:

```
Date             Date_Year        Date_month
2020-06-15          2020              06
2019-07-23          2019              07
Data non available  0000              00
```

Comment: You can use the "str.fullmatch" method with an appropriate regular expression to check if the string follows the date format.

Comment: Since `'Data non available '` is not a valid datetime format you can set the flag `errors` in the method `pd.to_datetime`  to `'coerce'`  or `'ignore'` .
Example:  `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd replace `Data not available` with NaT (**N**ot **A** **T**ime - NaN equivalent for dates/times) before you call `to_datetime`:

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace({'Data non available': pd.NaT})
```

Then

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date_Year'], df['Date_month'] = df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
        Date  Date_Year  Date_month
0 2020-06-15     2020.0         6.0
1 2019-07-23     2019.0         7.0
2        NaT        NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to convert the `'Data non available'` to the format `'0000-00-00'`? `pandas.to_datetime` will not like that. I'm assuming that you just want to mark them as missing.

In that case you can use `pandas.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'`. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

> **errors {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’**
>
> - If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
> - If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.
> - If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df['Date_Year'], df['Date_month'] = df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month

>>> df

        Date  Date_Year  Date_month
0 2020-06-15     2020.0         6.0
1 2019-07-23     2019.0         7.0
2        NaT        NaN         NaN
```

---

However, you may have dates that are not `'Data non available'` but couldn't be correctly parsed for some reason. By using `errors = 'coerce'` you wouldn't know that and couldn't identify the problem because they would be automatically converted to NaTs (Not a Time). To make sure you only convert `'Data non available'` to NaTs, you can mask only the remaining values before converting to datetime

```
mask = df['Date'] == 'Data non available'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].mask(mask))
df['Date_Year'], df['Date_month'] = df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month

>>> df

        Date  Date_Year  Date_month
0 2020-06-15     2020.0         6.0
1 2019-07-23     2019.0         7.0
2        NaT        NaN         NaN
```

Comment: The `errors='coerce'` bit is really cool. It will handle other possible variants of `Data non/not available` too.